# How to translate this AutoCAD VBA code into Python?

Tags: python, vba, autocad

I'm trying to automate some drawing in AutoCAD using Python and I work with SelectOnScreen method.
Here is a code in VBA:

```
Dim FilterType(0) As Integer
Dim FilterData(0) As Variant
FilterType(0) = 0
FilterData(0) = "TEXT"
selection.SelectOnScreen FilterType, FilterData
```

In Python I use it as:

```
FilterType = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_I2, [0]) 
FilterData = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, ['TEXT'])
selection.SelectOnScreen(FilterType, FilterData)
```

and it works  in AutoCAD.
However I want to select different types of object (texts and mtexts) and I have an example of code in VBA. So how to translate the following VBA code into Python?

```
Dim FilterType(1) As Integer
Dim FilterData(1) As Variant
FilterType(0) = 0
FilterData(0) = "Text"
FilterType(1) = 0
FilterData(1) = "MText"
selection.SelectOnScreen FilterType, FilterData
```

Here is my attempt of Python code I've tried, but it doesn't work in AutoCAD:

```
FilterType = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_I2, [0, 0]) 
FilterData = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, ["MTEXT", "TEXT"])
selection.SelectOnScreen(FilterType, FilterData)
```

Nothing selects when I try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your code fails to select anything is because the selection filter has an implicit **AND** logic, hence an object cannot be both `TEXT` *and* `MTEXT`.

Since the selection filter will permit a wildcard match, you can use the following:

```
FilterType = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_I2, [0]) 
FilterData = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, ['TEXT,MTEXT'])
selection.SelectOnScreen(FilterType, FilterData)
```

Or, if you're not fussed about the possibility of selecting `RTEXT`:

```
FilterType = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_I2, [0]) 
FilterData = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, ['*TEXT'])
selection.SelectOnScreen(FilterType, FilterData)
```

You can alternatively use the logical operators `<OR` and `OR>` in conjunction with the group code `-4`:

```
FilterType = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_I2, [-4, 0, 0, -4]) 
FilterData = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, ['<OR', 'TEXT', 'MTEXT', 'OR>'])
selection.SelectOnScreen(FilterType, FilterData)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I needed exactly.