# Variant Errors with Win32com, Python and AutoCAD

Tags: python, win32com, autocad

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408992/how-to-translate-this-autocad-vba-code-into-python), I am trying to use python and win32com.client to manipulate an open AutoCAD file, and gather all objects from a given layer into a selection set:

```
from comtypes.client import *
from comtypes.automation import *
import win32com.client

acad = GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.ActiveDocument
SSet = doc.SelectionSets[0]

FilterType = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_I2, [8]) 
FilterData = win32com.client.VARIANT(VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, ["Layer1"])
SSet.Select(5, FilterType, FilterData)
```

The select command bombs with the following error message:

```
ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Cannot put win32com.client.VARIANT(8194, [8]) in VARIANT
```

I vaguely understand the error inasmuch as it is complaining about the type/format of the second argument (and probably the third, if it got that far) but I do not understand why:  It seems to be telling me that it cannot accept a particular VARIANT in a slot that wants a VARIANT, but I don't know why.

Bear in mind when answering that I am proficient in python, in AutoCAD, and in old-school AutoLISP coding, but know almost nothing about win32com (or any other com), about variants in particular, or about getting AutoCAD to work with python.

(For the other old-schoolers:  I'm trying to mimic an SSGET command.)

Comment: @LeeMac taking a chance and reaching out-- just noticed the answer I cited is yours.  I've learned quite a bit from your site over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'm not very experienced with selection sets and so I stumbled across a solution without using them. The code below is an example of looping through each of the objects in the model space, checking if it has a specific layer, and builds a string that will select all the objects via `SendCommand`.

I believe you could actually use `SendCommand` to manipulate selection sets as well. (similar to `(command "ssget")` in autolisp) I just personally found this solution much easier to work out.

```
# I personally had better luck with comtypes than with win32com
import comtypes.client
try:
    # Get an active instance of AutoCAD
    app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application', dynamic=True)
except WindowsError: # No active instance found, create a new instance.
    app = comtypes.client.CreateObject('AutoCAD.Application', dynamic=True)
    # if you receive dispatch errors on the line after this one, a sleep call can
    # help so it's not trying to dispatch commands while AutoCAD is still starting up.
    # you could put it in a while statement for a fuller solution

app.Visible = True
doc = app.ActiveDocument
# if you get the best interface on an object, you can investigate its properties with 'dir()'
m = comtypes.client.GetBestInterface(doc.ModelSpace)
handle_string = 'select'
for entity in m:
    if entity.Layer == 'Layer1':
        handle_string += ' (handent "'+entity.Handle+'")'

handle_string += '\n\n'
doc.SendCommand(handle_string)
```

Comment: This was not the answer I asked for, but it was the answer I actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA reference the signature is:

```
object.Select Mode[, Point1][, Point2][, FilterType][, FilterData]
```

Try this:

```
SSet.Select(5, None,  None,  FilterType, FilterData)
```